# Google OAuth2 - Correct Usage?

Tags: google-authentication, google-oauth

I am developing REST API secured using Google OAuth2 (using java if that matters). The approach is as follows:

- UI is authenticating through Google and has: `google id` + `token id`,
- `google id` + `token id` are both sent on each request to API as headers,
- REST API uses URL https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=token_id to obtain JSON similar to below (where `token_id` come from request header):

JSON:

```
 {  
  "iss": "accounts.google.com",  
  "iat": "14791197651",  
  "exp": "14795233651",  
  "at_hash": "xDLxhM85hTYU0KwU-rhPgg",  
  "aud": "541950199239-s1fag9iaes0s99g4feipe0ih0l75km1l.apps.googleusercontent.com",  
  "sub": "197763402127980067798",  
  "azp": "541950819239-s5fag9iaes9s99g4feipe0ih0l75km1l.apps.googleusercontent.com",  
  "alg": "RS256",  
  "kid": "db9e3d7cdd1b4178010f89af11cfd37400061afc"  
 }
```

and compares `sub` value to `google id` from the request header,

- if the check passes and user by `google id` is in our database, then user is authorized to use the REST API (additional logic might be applied).

Is that correct workflow or additional checks need to be done?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth), if you're going to use the `tokeninfo` endpoint (which you are), you need just the `id_token`, and then you must also

> check that the aud claim contains one of your app's client IDs

so that you can not only validate the token, but ensure it's actually intended for your client.

Ergo, you can just pull the user's unique Google ID from the `sub` claim, no need to match it against the one received by the client.